# How I can get the changes of a TClientDataset to another TClientDataset?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, tclientdataset

How can I get from a `TClientDataset` the changes?

I have a `TClientDataset` named `GetDataset` and I have a grid. I want the changes in a new `TClientDataset` named `ChangeDataset`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want ChangeDataset to contain *only* the records in your first ClientDataSet which have been changed, or all of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a source ClientDataSet CDS1, you should be able to copy the changed records to a second ClientDataSet CDS2 by doing

```
if CDS1.ChangeCount > 0 then 
  CDS2.Data := CDS1.Delta;
```

As you'll see if you try that, it gives you a "before" record and one with the change(s).  That may not necessarily be what you want - frankly you'd do best to read the Whipple article posted in a comment and in the OLH to get the exact result you might be wanting to achieve. The point is, all the information you need is in the source CDS until you flush it away (by calling ApplyUpdates() - after that, if it succeeds, the change log is empty).

If you look at the rows in CDS2, it's not immediately obvious how you tell whether a particular field contains a changed value and how you distinguish one that does from one which is just empty.  Istr there was a very good post quite a long time ago in one of the Borland NTTP newsgroups by their Mark Edington, I think, explaining how to do this.  Basically, it's a question of evaluating VarIsClear on the field's NewValue property:

```
if VarIsClear(CDS2.Fields[i].NewValue) then 
// means Fields[i] does not have a changed value
```

Incidentally, since you can save the state of a CDS to XML, you can use XML manipulations, e.g. with a DOM parser such is the Windows built-in one (see MSXML.Pas) to do easily many things which are troublesome to do using the TDataSet paradigm.

Comment: Article from Eric Whipple http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32227#AuditTrail

Comment: @SirRufo:  Many thanks for the reference, very useful.